# _nano_vet_and_size_of_live in objective c stack trace

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am getting an odd exception in a CoreData (on iOS 10) request that does not seem to happen dependably, I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions. The code does not permit any nil pointers in the fetch request, so it isn't that. The stack trace is below, stemming from a fairly simple fetch:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == %@ AND active == 1", activeUser];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray* result = [syncContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1a6014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e26e450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018e11a3e0 abort + 140
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018e1eaa38 _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 0
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018e1ecbf0 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 392
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018e1ebb3c nano_malloc + 44
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018e1da2c4 malloc_zone_malloc + 172
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6c0c9c 0x18f6be000 + 11420 (sqlite3_config + 1344)
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f756f90 0x18f6be000 + 626576 (sqlite3_rekey + 1824)
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6fdfa4 0x18f6be000 + 262052 (sqlite3_log + 90728)
10  libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6f0a94 0x18f6be000 + 207508 (sqlite3_log + 36184)
11  libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6cb238 0x18f6be000 + 53816 (sqlite3_exec + 10664)
12  libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6cab90 0x18f6be000 + 52112 (sqlite3_exec + 8960)
13  libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6c9dc0 0x18f6be000 + 48576 (sqlite3_exec + 5424)
14  libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6c94ac 0x18f6be000 + 46252 (sqlite3_exec + 3100)
15  libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f6c9068 0x18f6be000 + 45160 (sqlite3_exec + 2008)
16  CoreData                        0x00000001914a2574 -[NSSQLiteConnection prepareSQLStatement:] + 472
17  CoreData                        0x00000001915c8364 -[NSSQLiteConnection selectRowsWithStatement:cached:] + 60
18  CoreData                        0x00000001915d7684 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1112
19  CoreData                        0x000000019166d670 _executeFetchRequest + 72
20  CoreData                        0x0000000191668904 -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] + 60
21  CoreData                        0x000000019157ce98 __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke + 260
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e0611c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e06e860 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
24  CoreData                        0x000000019157cd34 -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] + 208
25  CoreData                        0x0000000191642ec4 -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] + 288
26  CoreData                        0x00000001915abd04 -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] + 200
27  CoreData                        0x00000001915a6bc4 -[NSSQLCore processFetchRequest:inContext:] + 108
28  CoreData                        0x00000001914a9518 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504
29  CoreData                        0x0000000191589844 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 4512
30  CoreData                        0x0000000191581f90 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 276
31  CoreData                        0x00000001914a91cc -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 408
32  CoreData                        0x00000001914a7bf4 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 572
```

Comment: Post more of your code and whatever error message(s) you get. All that stack trace says is that you crashed while attempting a fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is fixed with iOS 10.2

Comment: Great, curious where you saw that it was fixed?

Comment: We had many crashes before iOS 10.2. But none of them seems to be reproduced after iOS 10.2

Comment: @dracula I can still see this crash on 10.2.1

Comment: @dracula I'm also having similar crashes on 10.2.1

Comment: I'm also experiencing this crash on 10.2. Similar crash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519574/core-data-crash-occurring-since-ios-10/43899423 seems to be fixed in 10.3.
Did anyone check on 10.3 is it reproducible?