# Core data crash occurring since iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios10

I've been struggling to resolve a locally-unreproducible crash since iOS 10 within the sqlite/coredata library. It's occurring very infrequently - somewhere in the realm of 0.2% in production.

What I know (or at least suspect):

- It only happens on iOS 10 and above.
- Most often occurs while saving the context, but may also be occurring during a core data fetch request.
- Occurring fairly rarely (ballpark rate of 0.15% of sessions)
- I have run stress tests with concurrency debug flags enabled, as well as some of the xcode memory management tools. No issues detected.
- Tested for memory leaks.
- I've never been able to reproduce this stacktrace in a development environment.
- No exceptions are being thrown prior to the crash. The entire code is wrapped.
- This action is performed within a block, and the app is in the foreground.
- Occurs seemingly at random during normal app operation. (Not at initialization time or anything special)
- It's a SIGABRT crash

> libsystem_kernel.dylib0x00000001841c3014 __pthread_kill+4
>       libsystem_c.dylib0x0000000184137400 abort+136
>       libsystem_malloc.dylib0x0000000184207a5c nanozone_error+328
>       libsystem_malloc.dylib0x0000000184209028 nano_realloc+644
>       libsystem_malloc.dylib0x00000001841fb240 malloc_zone_realloc+176
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x0000000185730c34 sqlite3_value_text+1220
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x0000000185777f38 sqlite3_rekey+1564
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x000000018578df78 sqlite3_rekey+91740
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x0000000185791c88 sqlite3_rekey+107372
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x000000018571df98 sqlite3_log+86448
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x0000000185757780 sqlite3_bind_int+11992
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x00000001856f1c80 sqlite3_exec+35188
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x00000001856eb608 sqlite3_exec+8956
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x00000001856ea838 sqlite3_exec+5420
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x00000001856e9f24 sqlite3_exec+3096
>       libsqlite3.dylib0x00000001856e9ae0 sqlite3_exec+2004
>       CoreData0x00000001874f1284 -[NSSQLiteConnectionprepareSQLStatement:]+468
>       CoreData0x00000001876166f0 -[NSSQLiteConnectionupdateRow:forRequestContext:]+496
>       CoreData0x00000001876c3430 _writeChangesForSaveRequest+1596
>       CoreData0x00000001876c4958 _executeSaveChangesRequest+312
>       CoreData0x00000001876ba7f4 -[NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContextexecuteRequestUsingConnection:]+40
>       CoreData0x00000001875cdaf8 __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManagerhandleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke+256
>       libdispatch.dylib0x000000018407e1bc _dispatch_client_callout+12
>       libdispatch.dylib0x000000018408b7f0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke+80
>       CoreData0x00000001875cd994 -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManagerhandleStoreRequest:]+204
>       CoreData0x0000000187693f80 -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManagerrouteStoreRequest:]+284
>       CoreData0x00000001875fb7e4 -[NSSQLCoredispatchRequest:withRetries:]+196
>       CoreData0x00000001875f7560 -[NSSQLCoreprocessSaveChanges:forContext:]+200
>       CoreData0x00000001874f8360 -[NSSQLCoreexecuteRequest:withContext:error:]+744
>       CoreData0x00000001875da2f4 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorexecuteRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke+3248
>       CoreData0x00000001875d2bf0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_routeHeavyweightBlock:]+272
>       CoreData0x00000001874f7f20 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorexecuteRequest:withContext:error:]+404
>       CoreData0x00000001875195ac -[NSManagedObjectContextsave:]+2768

Here's what the code generally looks like:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [[MyManagedObject alloc] init];

// This is actually within the init method
NSEntityDescription *desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass(object.class)
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

[object initWithEntity:desc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];


// later on...
[context performBlock:^{

    // Fetch another (different) object from core data
    NSArray *fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // Changing some properties of object with values from fetched results
    object.property = fetchResults[0].property;

    // insert the object
    [context insertObject:object];

    // save the context
    [context save:&error]
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I found this release note that coincided with iOS 10.2, which may have caused some existing issue(s) to be exposed. It's not clear what the change was, or how it might cause problems, but it seems pretty likely that this is related somehow.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207422
Impact: Processing malicious strings may lead to an unexpected application termination or arbitrary code execution
Description: A memory corruption issue existed in the processing of strings. This issue was addressed through improved bounds checking.
CVE-2016-7663

Comment: Core-data context are not thread safe neither for reading or for writing. If you violate this core-data can fail at any time and in any way. That means that it may crash with hard to diagnose crash reports even at points in the code where you are on the correct thread.  I would check your code for a thread-safety violation.  I would start with looking at any  function that pass managedObjects as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am using the concurrency flag '-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1' while testing the app, and it hasn't flagged anything on the latest builds. I have also combed through the code manually because I also suspected a concurrency issues initially. Unfortunately, this error is still occurring despite this.

Comment: If it is happening in only 0.5% of the builds the line of code (or then combination of circumstances) may be very rare and hard to find by exercising the code. Sometimes a code review can do more to find these kinds of issues.

Comment: @Kieran, do you have a solution to this issue? I'm experiencing the similar one starting iOS 10.

Comment: We no longer see this as of iOS 10.3.

Google analytics also exhibited the same crash - they too no longer see it on iOS 10.3.

Root cause is still unknown to me.

Answer (score 1):

If the majority of your code base is, as your suggest, asynchronous and you are trying to perform a synchronous save operation within this asynchronous block, there is every reason to suspect that is why you're receiving the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` error in the error message.

The key is the issue with the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` (PSC) failing to properly coordinate the data save. Unless I'm mistaken the error message identifies that the PSC is locked when you ask the PSC to respond to the call to save for that MOC.

In my humble opinion your problem *still* most likely stems from your call to `performBlock`... in this code you're performing a fetch request, then updating a property, then inserting the object back into the MOC, then saving, all in the same block. These are very different functions taking different amounts of processing power and time, all dumped into one single concurrency block.

Also, how you instantiate a property when using concurrency and blocks is important. You may need to check where in your code is most appropriate to instantiate your properties.

So some questions...

1. Do you need every line of this code in a performBlock? Consider that, unless you're blocking your UI, the fetch request and the update to your property may be ok in code outside the call to `performBlock`.
2. If you do need every line of this code in a core data concurrency block such as `performBlock`, have you considered instead embedding your call to `save` in a "block-within-a-block" and using `performBlockAndWait`?

The [Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) has an example of embedding a `save` call into a `performBlockAndWait` block, included (in part) following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = '…; //Our primary context on the main queue

NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[private setParentContext:moc];

[private performBlock:^{
    'Complete your fetch request and update the managed object's property.

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![private save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![moc save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
     }];
}];
```

If you're able to update your question with a little more code and a more detailed description I might be able to provide a more accurate fix for your specific problem.

Also I'd recommend you do some research...

Despite the age of the book, the concepts of concurrency are still very well explained in "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013 from The Pragmatic Bookshelf) by Marcus S. Zarra, and in particular Chapter 4 titled "Performance Tuning” and Chapter 5 titled "Threading”.

Another valuable book on core data from Apress publishers – "Pro iOS Persistence Using Core Data", by Michael Privat and Robert Warner.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I should have mentioned that the 'context' object I reference above is a private managed object context with PrivateQueueConcurrencyType already. The majority of the code base is independent and asynchronous from the main queue. In this cause, i don't believe the double block would really gain us anything (although it's an interesting concept for sure)

Comment: I have also discovered (since I posted this yesterday) that there have been similar reports of memory issues independent of core data reported here:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/207825
and here: 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63546

I' starting to suspect an Apple iOS10 memory management issue.

Comment: I might misunderstand your situation, but I believe you have a lot to gain from including the double block. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

No longer occurs as of iOS 10.3. Root cause is still unknown. Assuming some iOS memory management break in 10.2, with a fix in 10.3.